Split Pauli Four-vector as quadratic terms of spinors
If I have the Pauli Four-vector $$x_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
t+z & x-i y \\
x+i y & t-z
\end{array}\right)$$ with $\sigma^0$ as Identity Matrix. Is there some way to write it as quadratic terms of spinors? In this case, spinors would encapsulate coordinates as entries of their components.

Please double check the correctness of your equation: $x_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
-t+z & x-i y \
x+i y & t-z
\end{array}\right)$. Are you sure about the changing sign of $t$?

In diagonal, t+z and t-z
It has this format. I edited correctly now

Is the WP detail on Weyl's surjective homomorphism not clear? 4-vectors map to pairs of spinor indices.

Near duplicate and linked questions.

I didn't understand yet. I want to split the matrix in spinors as columns 2x1 (two scalar functions of coordinates). Is there a straightforward method to do it?

Why would you "want" that? Hitting the matrix $\sigma^\mu$ with a Dirac spinor on each side yields an object transforming as a four-vector. It is not clear what you have not mastered about the spinor map. Have you slugged through a standard QFT text?
